# Changing notations for probability moments with subscripts

Tags: probability-or-statistics, output-formatting, replacement

Suppose I have have two kinds of variables $X_{\alpha_j}, X_{\beta_k}$ in the form of `Subscript[x,Subscript[α,j]]` and `Subscript[x,Subscript[β,k]]`. These two variables are embedded in a long expression for which I want to replace their symbols. Assume that I have already applied `Expand` to such an expression so that the terms in question are nicely isolated.

**Question:** How can one write an *association* rule, that takes in `Subscript[x,Subscript[α,j]]` and `Subscript[x,Subscript[β,k]]`, and replaces them such that it satisfies *all* three of the following at the same time:

**(1)** $X_{\alpha_j} \mapsto \mu_{\alpha_j}$ and $X_{\beta_k} \mapsto \mu_{\beta_k}$; so the result should have the form `Subscript[μ,Subscript[α,j]]` and `Subscript[μ,Subscript[β,k]]`, respectively.

**(2)** $X_{\alpha_j} X_{\beta_k} \mapsto c_{\alpha_j, \beta_k} + \mu_{\alpha_j} \mu_{\beta_k}$ (and also the same map when the terms are commuted; so $X_{\beta_k} X_{\alpha_j}$ yields the same result; so the result (and its commuted form) should have the form `Plus[Times[Subscript[μ,Subscript[α,j]],Subscript[μ,Subscript[β,k]]],Subscript[c,Subscript[α,j],Subscript[β,k]]]`

**(3)** $X_{\alpha_j}^2 \mapsto \sigma_{\alpha_j}^2 + \mu_{\alpha_j}^2$ and $X_{\beta_k}^2 \mapsto \sigma_{\beta_k}^2 + \mu_{\beta_k}^2$; so the result should have the form `Plus[Power[Subscript[μ,Subscript[α,j]],2],Power[Subscript[σ,Subscript[α,j]],2]]`, and `Plus[Power[Subscript[μ,Subscript[β,k]],2],Power[Subscript[σ,Subscript[β,k]],2]]`, respectively.

*Remark:* As one may can already guess from the notations being used, I'm simply taking a sequence of random variables $X_{\alpha_j}, X_{\beta_k}$,  after taking expectations, rewriting them into their conventional mean, variance and covariances. I assume the expressions in question only involve up to the usual second moments, and hence expressions like $X_{\alpha_j}^3$ or $X_{\alpha_j} X_{\beta_k}^2$ are not of a concern.

Comment: [**strongly**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/193) related. Point 2.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks! I should've read that a long time ago before I started this project. Unfortunately at this point, I've accumulated so much stuff that it's too difficult to rewrite things in a different symbol. But thanks for the reference, useful to keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try with this list of rules, in this order since your transformations are overlapping:

```
rules = {
    Power[Subscript[X_,Subscript[a_,j_]], n_] :>
        Power[Subscript[σ,Subscript[a,j]], n]+
        Power[Subscript[μ,Subscript[a,j]], n],
    Times[rest1___,
        Subscript[X_,Subscript[a_,j_]],
        Subscript[X_,Subscript[b_,k_]],
        rest2___
    ] :> Times[Subscript[c,Subscript[a,j],Subscript[b,k]], rest1, rest2],
    Subscript[X_,Subscript[a_,j_]] :>
         Subscript[μ,Subscript[a,j]]
}
```

In the multiplication case, additional terms are preserved.

The transformations are applied with:

```
expr /. rules
```

or with

```
expr //. rules
```

if multiple transformation passes are required.

Comment: Works! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm just wondering if you could amend your code slightly? In my `expr`, I have other symbols that are also subscripted, say $Y_{\rho_m}$. But using your current `rules`, applying it to `Subscript[Y,Subscript[\[Rho],m]]` would change it to `Subscript[\[Mu],Subscript[\[Rho],k]]` as well. Is it possible to amend the code so that the subscript changes only affect those that are subscripted by `X`? Thanks so much!

Comment: Oh never mind. Silly me. I just needed to remove `_` everywhere where you wrote `X_`. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for the delay: I am on holidays and do not connect ofter. Anyway you could manage the situation properly!

Comment: Thanks again for getting back! Really helpful!